# SML Case and pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching, sml, smlnj

I have the follwing function that is suppose to return the value of a card. I'm not sure why the case Num => Num is giving the following error:

> Error: Types of rules don't agree, Earlier rules rank->int this rule
>   rank->int->rank

Why would Num=>Num have the return type rank->int->rank

```
 datatype suit = Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts | Spades
 datatype rank = Jack | Queen | King | Ace | Num of int 
 type card = suit * rank


 fun card_value (suit, rank)=
 case rank of
    Ace =>11
     | Jack =>10
     | King =>10
     | Queen =>10
     | Num => Num ;


card_value(Clubs,Ace); //calling function
```

Comment: Coursera homework? ;-)

Comment: It absolutely is coursera homework. It sucks that peaople ask for answers and not do it on their own.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message is indicative. You need to have the same return type for all patterns.

```
fun card_value (suit, rank) =
  case rank of
      Ace => 14
    | King => 13
    | Queen => 12
    | Jack => 11
    | Num i => i
```

So you have to specify the correct constructor `Num i` (not `Num` only) and return `i` as an `int`